# encrypt password in a text file

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

I am defining my database in the php file

```
define ('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');

define ('DB_USERNAME', 'user');

define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');

define ('DB_DATABASE', 'dbase');
```

Is there a built in way I can store an encrypted / hashed password in a text file and then de encrypt it in the program rather than storing my password in my source code.

Comment: If your program can decrypt the password, anybody that has access to the file with the encrypted password very likely also has access to the file with the decryption code and can decrypt the password...

Comment: You should just nest the config file. If they have access to that level they will also have access to whatever you're trying to encrypt with

Comment: Instead of storing the plain text passwords then, you would have to keep a decryption key someplace in your code. This doesn't gain you further security, it just adds a minor obstacle.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.. What should  be  the best way. I do not want to store passwords in my source code..

Comment: Create your own function and hide your decryption key inside your code but it has to be scrambled as well.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to store passwords in your source? The best you can do is *obfuscation*. What does that really buy you?

Comment: I back up my source codes to repository thats accessible to lots of people.. beyond my group too..

Answer (score 0):

> I back up my source codes to repository thats accessible to lots of people.. beyond my group too..

Then what you want is to *separate* the sensitive configuration from the source code. Don't check it into the repository, keep it in a protected file somewhere on trusted computers and only deploy it to the production server separately from the code.